# Creating Check Pattern with nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a checkerboard pattern using `nth-child`, but it isn't working the way I expected it to.

In the example below, I want to set every other `p` at opposite sides of the `div` to create a checkerboard pattern. The `p` are set to `width:50%;`, and the `div` is set at `width:100%`.

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9ng7/) to demonstrate:

HTML

```
<div id='check'>
  <p>Odd</p>
</div>

<div id='check'>
  <p>Even</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#check { 
  float:left; 
  width: 100%;
}
#check p {  
  width: 50%;
  background: #DDD;
}

#check p:nth-child(odd) {
  float:right;
}
```

Can someone make me see how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep all the `p` elements together in a single `div`, as the `nth-child` is based off the parent container. [Here is a modified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/L9ng7/1/). It uses this code:

**HTML**

```
<div id ='check'>
    <p>Odd</p>
    <p>Even</p>
    <p>Odd</p>
    <p>Even</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#check { 
    float:left; 
    width: 100%;
}
#check p {  
    width: 50%;
    background: #DDD;
    clear:both;
}

#check p:nth-child(odd) {
    float:right;
}

#check p:nth-child(even) {
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't have 2 elements using the same id. I believe you want to switch to using classes.

Created a fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/wE6e4/

```
#checkerboard {
    width: 500px;
}

.check { 
    float:left; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.check:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #DDD;
}

.check:nth-child(even) {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It's actually a class in my CSS, and I've changed the jfiddle to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using an ID multiple times - ID's should be unique. Besides that, the line
`#check p:nth-child(odd)` means that you want to set the given rules for every odd `p` child of `#check`, which is not what you want. You want to make every odd `.check` (I took the liberty to change the ID's to a class). So you should put them in a container and say:

```
#cont .check:nth-child(odd) {
    float:right;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wbnks/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to minimize your CSS, you can try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="checkerboard">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkerboard p {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.checkerboard p:nth-child(4n-2), .checkerboard p:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9ng7/5/